# WatchKit App Cannot Connect to the Internet. Works on Simulator but not on Physical Device

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

This is my first WatchKit App.

I am working on an app that gets an API call to an iCal file and displays the time remaining in two events.

I am working on Xcode 13.4.1 and created an iOS app with watchOS app using swift and storyboard. I set the target deployment for the iOS app to 15.5, which is the highest version of iOS that my current version of Xcode will let me set. The target deployment for the watchOS app is set to version 6.2 because I have an Apple Watch series 2, and the latest version of watchOS is 6.3. I want the app to at least work for my watch. The code for the iOS app and watch app are pretty much the same. The app works as expected on the watch and phone simulators and on my physical iPhone 8 plus. The problem is that the app does not work on my physical watch.

I created a custom class called `API_Manager` that handles the API call. I handle my API call as a giant string because I am getting an iCal file and parse it later on in the class. `url` is defined above. Here is my API call for both the phone and watch app:

```
public func getData() throws{
        //api call
        do{
            // real url is defined above
            let url:String = ""
            savedData = try String(contentsOf: URL(string: url)!)
        } catch{
            print("there was an error with the api call")
            throw API_Error.apiCallError
        }
        // parsing data 
}
```

`getData()` is called in the `init` function of the `API_Manager` class.

```
    init() throws {
        // checking internet connection
        if (!NetworkMonitor.shared.isConnected){
            throw API_Error.noInternet
        }
        
        do{
            try getData()
        } catch{
            throw API_Error.apiCallError
        }
        
    }
```

I believe the root of the problem is an Internet connection. I check for an Internet connection before the API call, and if there is no Internet connection, then I throw a custom error. I used [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjJBRhPiM_I&t=662s) to create a `Network_Monitor` class. This is the `startMonitoring()` function which is called in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching()` in `extensionDelegate` of the watch app and application `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the `appDelegate`.

```
public func startMonitoring(){
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
        
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] path in
            self?.isConnected = path.status == .satisfied
            
            // getting connection type
            self?.getConnectionType(path)
        }
    }
```

I created a custom error that is thrown throughout the `API_Manager` if things don't work as expected. Here is how I created the custom errors:

```
enum API_Error: Error{
    case noInternet
    case apiCallError
}

extension API_Error: CustomStringConvertible{
    public var description:String {
        switch self{
        case .noInternet:
            return "Error: No internet connection"
        case .apiCallError:
            return "There was an error with the api call"
        }
        
    }
}
```

I created another enum that is used to display text on a label in the Interface Controller if a specific error is thrown.

```
enum API_Manager_Status{
        case active
        case noInternet
        case apiCallError
        case null                   // if the api manager is nill
    }
```

Here is how I used the two enums in `InterfaceController`:
`main()` is called in the `awake()` function.

```
func main(){
        do{
            apiManager = try API_Manager()
            apiManagerStatus = .active
        } catch API_Error.noInternet{
            apiManagerStatus = .noInternet
            
        } catch API_Error.apiCallError{
            apiManagerStatus = .apiCallError
            
        } catch{
            apiManagerStatus = .null
            
        }
        
        if (apiManagerStatus == .noInternet){
            periodLabel.setText("Error")
            timeRemaining.setText("No Internet")
            print(API_Error.noInternet)
        } else if (apiManagerStatus == .apiCallError){
            periodLabel.setText("Error")
            timeRemaining.setText("API Call")
            print(API_Error.apiCallError)
        } else if (apiManagerStatus == .null){
            periodLabel.setText("Error")
            timeRemaining.setText("Other Error")
            print("Cought all errors")
        } else{
            // main code to display time remaining
        }
```

So I guess my questions are:

- Why is my Apple Watch not getting an Internet connection?
- How can I fix my app if it worked on the simulators and iPhone, but not watch?
- Can the Apple Watch do an API call?
- Do I need to configure my app to connect with the iPhone, given that my watchOS verison is 6.2?

Sorry if this is a long question. This is my first time posting a question on Stack Overflow. I would appreciate any help. Let me know if I need to add any more information to help clear things up.

I have tried many potential solutions to fix the problem, but none have worked:

- I distributed the app on Test Flight and had my dad download it. He has an Apple Watch Series 4 running on watchOS 9.2, and the app still does not work on his watch.
- I have restarted my phone and watch multiple times and even tried to run the app with my phone off, so the watch could connect to wifi.
- I tried to install a watchOS 9 beta profile on my watch, knowing it would not work, but I still wanted to see what would happen.
- I tried setting the build target to watchOS 8.5, which is the highest my version of Xcode would allow, to see if the problem was watchOS 6.2, and if it would work on my dad's watch.
- Lastly, I tried adding privacy messages in the Info.plist for both the phone and the watch app. The messages did not display when I re-downloaded the app, but it still did not fix the issue.
  (the messages I used were: "Privacy - Nearby Interaction Usage Description" which does not work on watchOS 6.2, but I still kept in the info.plist, and "Privacy - Bluetooth Always Usage Description")

I know Apple Watches are supposed to use the connected phone for Internet and then wifi if a phone is not connected. My watch shows that my phone is connected, and I have tried it with just wifi. I believe my watch can still get an Internet connection because I can still use Siri and even go to the App Store on my watch, which needs an Internet connection. I would appreciate any help. Let me know if I need to add any more information to help clear things up.